# Should there be an "and" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> **Due to the nature of helicopter, external loads involving essential persons or equipment,** diligent review and compliance with the
>   manufacturer's balance data is required.

The bold part is confusing. Why is there no "and" between "helicopter" and "external"? Does it mean "due to the nature of (helicopter) and (external loads involving essential...)"?

Comment: Is the sentence quoted correctly? I can get some meaning, but it is at least very odd. "And" is the least of the problems, I think.

Comment: @virolino Yes, it is correctly quoted. I think the sentence makes sense if it's "Due to the nature of helicopter, diligent review and compliance with the manufacturer's balance data is required for external loads involving essential persons or equipment".

Comment: I agree (mostly) with the meaning you get. But it does not make the original any more "chewable". First, I would use "due to the nature of **the** helicopter". Second, it may want to say: "due to the nature of **the pair (helicopter, external loads...)**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a change of words may clarify this. Be careful, however, that the meaning can actually be wrong - the original is not "state-of-the-art".

> Due to the nature of **the** helicopter **and of the** external loads involving essential persons or equipment, diligent review and compliance with the manufacturer's balance data is required.

Even though it adds some understanding, I am still not satisfied with the result.

If this is what the authors wanted to say, then **you were right** to add **and** - with the note that some other words were needed.